# add the differents count(*) of a group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have this query :

```
 select count(*), extract(month from my_table_date), extract(year from my_table_date)
 from my_table
 group by extract(year from my_table_date), extract(month from my_table_date)
 order by extract(year from my_table_date), extract(month from my_table_date);
```

I have a result like this :

```
       75                       11                    2020
       56                       12                    2020
       91                        1                    2021
       102                        2                    2021
```

I would like to add all of the count(*) (column 1) values in the same query. is that possible ?

thank you

Comment: Can you also specify the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROLLUP`:

```sql
SELECT count(*),
       extract(month from my_table_date) AS month,
       extract(year from my_table_date) as year
FROM   my_table
GROUP BY
       ROLLUP(
         extract(year from my_table_date),
         extract(month from my_table_date)
       )
HAVING GROUPING_ID(
         extract(year from my_table_date),
         extract(month from my_table_date)
       ) IN (0,3)
ORDER BY
       year, month;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (my_table_date) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-11-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 75 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-12-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 56 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 91 UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 102;
```

Outputs:

> | COUNT(*) | MONTH | YEAR |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 75 | 11 | 2020 |
> | 56 | 12 | 2020 |
> | 91 | 1 | 2021 |
> | 102 | 2 | 2021 |
> | 324 |  |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1876569e3b59e629925425e964981d60)*